# Pass data to another page

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to pass some data from one page to another page by using jquery but it dose not working, below is the code which I want to click the text in source page and the destination page will hide the current text.

Source page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("a.pass").bind("click", function () {
        var url = "Destination.html?name=" + encodeURIComponent($("a.pass").text());
        window.location.href = url;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a class="pass">a</a><br />
<a class="pass">b</a><br />
<a class="pass">c</a><br />
<a class="pass">d</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Destination page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var queryString = new Array();
$(function () {


    if (queryString.length == 0) {
        if (window.location.search.split('?').length > 1) {
            var params = window.location.search.split('?')[1].split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                var key = params[i].split('=')[0];
                var value = decodeURIComponent(params[i].split('=')[1]);
                queryString[key] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    if (queryString["name"] != null) {
        var data = queryString["name"]
        $("p.+'data'").hide();
    }
});

</script>

</head>

<body>
<p class="a">a</p>
<p class="b">b</p>
<p class="c">c</p>
<p class="d">d</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Source page, change `$("a.pass").text()` to `$(this).text()`. You want the text of just the clicked `<a>` element, but you were getting the text from all the `<a>` elements.

On the Destination page, change `$("p.+'data'")` to `$("p." + data)`. Your code was not performing string concatenation because everything inside the double quotes is a single string literal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 function GetQueryStringParams(sParam) {
        var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
            var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
            if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
                return sParameterName[1];
            }
        }
    }
  var data = GetQueryStringParams('name');
```